# Two use cases which access the same repository - how to avoid identical/ duplicate API calls?

Tags: android, clean-architecture, android-mvvm

I have two use cases `UseCase A` and `UseCase B` which access the same repository `Repo X`. `Repo X` makes a API (`data.com/getUserInfo`) call to get certain data.

`ViewModel 1` has need for only `UseCase B`, while `ViewModel 2` has need for both `UseCase A and B`. So, in case of `ViewModel 1`, the API call is made only once. While in case of `ViewModel 2`, the same API call is made twice even though a single API call would have been enough.

**My question is how to avoid the extra and duplicate API call in case of `ViewModel 2`?**

One way I can think of is extracting the API call in its own UseCase and then pass the response to `UseCase A` and `UseCase B` as constructor arguments. Would this be a viable way to avoid the duplicate calls? Can a UseCase just be an API call?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate calls"? Call is being made by the repo, so there are no duplicate definitions of the call. If you're talking about a HTTP request, then you can have cache to eliminate duplicates on any level you want, HTTP client level, repo level and UC level. Both client and repo level caching could serve the data from cache.

Comment: Yes, duplicate HTTP request - one made via `UseCase A` and one made via `UseCase B`. Cacheing makes sense. Thanks!